# How to define different possible types for one field in JSON Schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

For example, need to validate field GRADE - not blank string (which can be converted to integer) or integer between 1 and 1000

Comment: just read the documentation of jsonschema you will find the examples there

Comment: where? Read? Not found. Link please?

Comment: this will help https://json-schema.org/learn/getting-started-step-by-step

Answer (score 1):

The most basic definition would be:

```
      "GRADE": {
        "type": ["string", "integer"],
        "pattern": "^[0-9]+$"
      }
```

Take a look at the `pattern` keyword as described in detail here: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html#id6

You can define a regular expression that meets your exact requirements for the GRADE field.

Comment: how would you restrict the min and max numbers?

Comment: So the person who just gives links to some documentation is now asking for details?

Comment: No, the question itself was asking for a range of numbers, not a pattern of single digits

Comment: I mean you answer can validate any value like `000000000` or `287892929029092929827` etc..

Comment: True, but the way the question is written I am afraid there are more constraints we are not aware of.

Comment: OP said string or number not both read the question carefully before answering

Comment: Please tell me how the property value can be of both types at the same time?

Comment: `"pattern": "[0-9]"` only checks that there is a digit somewhere in the string; to check that it consists only of digits, the pattern must be anchored with `^` and `$`.

Comment: or, alternatively, one could do `"not": { "pattern": "[^0-9]" }`, but that would probably give a less readable error message on validation failure.